# How to split table into two tables based on column value in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014-express

I need to split a table into two tables based on a value of column by creating two tables in `data-base` for example:

I have a table as the below

`table1`

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Col1         |     Col2         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         1           |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         2           |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         3           |         b        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         4           |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         5           |         b        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         6           |         b        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         7           |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

and the result I want to be like this as the below tables

`table2`

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Col1         |     Col2         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         1           |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         2           |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         4           |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         7           |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

`table3`

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Col1         |     Col2         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         3           |         b        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         5           |         b        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         6           |         b        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `SELECT...INTO` statement:

```
create table #table1 (col1 int, col2 char(1))

insert into #table1 
values
 (1,'a')
,(2,'a')
,(3,'b')
,(4,'a')
,(5,'b')
,(6,'b')
,(7,'a')

select Col1, Col2 into #table2
from #table1
where Col2 = 'a'

select Col1, Col2 into #table3
from #table1
where Col2 = 'b'
```

Here are the resulting `#table2` and `#table3`:

[image]